# What special meaning have slash "/" inside character class

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

In docs I can't find anything. But for pattern work properly in character class I need to escape `/` like this `"\/".` Why I need do so? Sorry for my english. I'm using PCRE and preg_match function. Oh my God, sorry all and thanks for help. I'm using `/` delimiters.

Comment: I don't think it's a special character...

Comment: You're probably using a dialect where `/` is a regexp delimiter (Javascript, Perl...). In this case, yes, you have to escape it.

Comment: [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?_`{}|~/.-] Check this pattern please.

Comment: @thg435 you are free to use any other non-whitespace char as a delimiter in perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know only one case when you should do it if you use regular expression like this one:

**/something here / something here /**. I mean that / is start and end bound of your reg. exr.

Answer (score 1):

While `/` might not have any meaning in the context of the regular expression itself, depending on the programming language, `/` might be used to encapsulate the regex string, and would therefore need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to escape `/` in `[...]`

`[/]` should work.

and in regex, `/` doesn't have special meaning. it is literal slash.

Comment: That's true in JavaScript, but not Perl, Ruby, PHP . . .

Comment: @ruakh I said `in regex` when I posted my answer, the question was only tagged with `regex`, nothing more. also without the new stuff about `preg_match` either.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. Surely you don't believe that a question that asks about regex, without mentioning the language, must necessarily mean JavaScript regexes?

Comment: @ruakh why regex question without mentioning language must be javascript related? it could be vim/java/python/shell/awk/grep.... and I am not familiar with javascript.. :(  I guess we have some misunderstanding...

Comment: Well, you wrote, "you don't have to escape `/` in `[...]`"; that statement is *meaningfully* true in some languages/tools (for example, JavaScript, GNU sed, and GNU AWK all allow `/[/]/`), and misleading-but-true in languages/tools where you don't have to escape `/` *anywhere* in a regex (such as Java, Python, and grep), but *wrong* in languages/tools like Perl, Ruby, and PHP (where the only way to avoid having to escape `/` is to use a less-common regex delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the regular expression itself but how it is getting parsed by the language. For example in Ruby:

```
 "/".match(/[/]/)
```

is a syntax error  but:

```
 "/".match(/[\/]/)
```

will work.